# Google Cloud Platform: How to pass a multi-line Secrets Manager secret into a Cloudbuild / Docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I'm using Laravel with Laravel Passport which generates the files /storage/oauth-private.key and /storage/oauth-public.key. I uploaded these keys to Google secret manager. The keys are multi-line and resemble this format (condensed):

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJQgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCCSwwggkoAgEAAoICAQDuwBj9dH90mdHy
...
hTGc7jCAhvT1w36bhILk4+mc9yl2Zw==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Here's the first two steps of the cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
# Add service account from secrets
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: "bash"
  args: ["-c", "mkdir -p /workspace/secrets && echo $$SERVICE_ACCOUNT > /workspace/secrets/key.json"]
  secretEnv: ["SERVICE_ACCOUNT"]
  id: Key
# Build the container image
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    cp /workspace/secrets/key.json ./purgatory/ \
    && docker build -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-api-purgatory:$COMMIT_SHA \
    --build-arg CLOUDSQL_USERNAME=$$CLOUDSQL_USERNAME \
    --build-arg CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD=$$CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD \
    --build-arg CLOUDSQL_DATABASE=$$CLOUDSQL_DATABASE \
    --build-arg CLOUDSQL_PBDATABASE=$$CLOUDSQL_PBDATABASE \
    --build-arg CLOUDSQL_SOCKET=$$CLOUDSQL_SOCKET \
    --build-arg OAUTH_PRIVATE_KEY=$$OAUTH_PRIVATE_KEY \
    --build-arg OAUTH_PUBLIC_KEY=$$OAUTH_PUBLIC_KEY \
    -f ./purgatory/Dockerfile ./purgatory
  secretEnv: ['CLOUDSQL_DATABASE','CLOUDSQL_PBDATABASE','CLOUDSQL_USERNAME','CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD','CLOUDSQL_SOCKET','OAUTH_PRIVATE_KEY','OAUTH_PUBLIC_KEY']
  id: Build
```

When I run the build step in Cloud build, I get this output:

```
BUILD
Starting Step #0 - "Key"
Step #0 - "Key": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Finished Step #0 - "Key"
Starting Step #1 - "Build"
Step #1 - "Build": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #1 - "Build": bad flag syntax: -----END
Step #1 - "Build": See 'docker build --help'.
Finished Step #1 - "Build"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 125
```

The "Build: bad flag syntax: -----END" feedback seems to indicate that the key file contents are being read as multiple parts and maybe interpreting that "-----END" is a command flag as opposed to the end of the string value as it's supposed to be.  The end goal is that during the cloudbuild and dockerbuild process, I want to output the secret keys into the container's storage/ directory where they're normally first-created. What's the best practice for this?

**EDIT**

Here's the Dockerfile with some small business-related .env fields removed:

```
FROM alpine:3.17

# Setup document root
WORKDIR /var/www/html
ARG CLOUDSQL_USERNAME
ARG CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD
ARG CLOUDSQL_DATABASE
ARG CLOUDSQL_SOCKET
ARG OAUTH_PRIVATE_KEY
ARG OAUTH_PUBLIC_KEY

# Install packages
RUN apk add --no-cache \
  curl \
  nginx \
  php81 \
  php81-ctype \
  php81-curl \
  php81-dom \
  php81-fpm \
  php81-gd \
  php81-intl \
  php81-mbstring \
  php81-mysqli \
  php81-opcache \
  php81-openssl \
  php81-phar \
  php81-session \
  php81-sodium \
  php81-xml \
  php81-xmlreader \
  php81-zip \
  php81-tokenizer \
  php81-fileinfo \
  php81-xmlwriter \
  php81-pdo_mysql \
  supervisor \
  bash \
  nano \
  fcgi

# copy in nginx config
COPY docker-assets/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY docker-assets/nginx/conf.d/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/

# Configure PHP-FPM
COPY docker-assets/php/fpm-pool.conf /etc/php81/php-fpm.d/www.conf
#COPY docker-assets/php/php.ini /etc/php81/conf.d/custom.ini

# Configure supervisord
COPY docker-assets/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Configure supervisord
COPY docker-assets/nginx_after_php_up.sh /var/www/nginx_after_php_up.sh
RUN chmod 755 /var/www/nginx_after_php_up.sh
RUN dos2unix /var/www/nginx_after_php_up.sh

#configure laravel
COPY docker-assets/php/laravel.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/laravel.ini

#install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/.composer/cache

# Make sure files/folders needed by the processes are accessable when they run under the nobody user
RUN chown -R nobody.nobody /var/www/html /run /var/lib/nginx /var/log/nginx /var/log/php81

# copy in app directories (there isn't a good way to selectively exclude paths)
COPY --chown=nobody:nobody   app        /var/www/html/app
COPY --chown=nobody:nobody   bootstrap  /var/www/html/bootstrap
COPY --chown=nobody:nobody   config     /var/www/html/config
COPY --chown=nobody:nobody   database   /var/www/html/database
COPY --chown=nobody:nobody   public     /var/www/html/public
COPY --chown=nobody:nobody   resources  /var/www/html/resources
COPY --chown=nobody:nobody   routes     /var/www/html/routes
COPY --chown=nobody:nobody   storage    /var/www/html/storage
COPY --chown=nobody:nobody   tests      /var/www/html/tests

#copy in app files
COPY --chown=nobody:nobody \
  .htaccess.prod \
  .htaccess.staging \
  .styleci.yml \
  .user.ini \
  .user.ini.prod \
  artisan \
  cloudbuild.yaml \
  composer.json \
  composer.lock \
  php-settings-monitor.php \
  phpunit.xml \
  README.md \
  /var/www/html/

COPY --chown=nobody:nobody   .env.gcloudsql     /var/www/html/.env
COPY --chown=nobody:nobody key.json /var/www/html/storage/gcp-service-account/
RUN sed -i -r "s|CLOUDSQL_USERNAME|${CLOUDSQL_USERNAME}|g" /var/www/html/.env
RUN sed -i -r "s|CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD|${CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD}|g" /var/www/html/.env
RUN sed -i -r "s|CLOUDSQL_DATABASE|${CLOUDSQL_DATABASE}|g" /var/www/html/.env
RUN sed -i -r "s|CLOUDSQL_SOCKET|${CLOUDSQL_SOCKET}|g" /var/www/html/.env

RUN cat /var/www/html/.env

# Make sure app files have the correct user (if they are mounted with volumes from docker compose we need this step)
#RUN chown -R nobody.nobody /var/www/html

USER nobody

# Laravel Passport oauth public and private keys
RUN echo "${OAUTH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /var/www/html/storage/oauth-private.key
RUN echo "${OAUTH_PUBLIC_KEY}" > /var/www/html/storage/oauth-public.key

#run composer to get dependancies
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction --no-progress

# Expose the port nginx is reachable on
EXPOSE 8080

# Let supervisord start nginx & php-fpm
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]

# Configure a healthcheck to validate that everything is up&running
HEALTHCHECK --timeout=10s CMD curl --silent --fail http://127.0.0.1:8080/fpm-ping
```

Also, in the cloudbuild.yaml I added quotes around the key value which made the error go away, though I'm still testing...

```
# Build the container image
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    cp /workspace/secrets/key.json ./purgatory/ \
    && docker build -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-api-purgatory:$COMMIT_SHA \
    --build-arg CLOUDSQL_USERNAME=$$CLOUDSQL_USERNAME \
    --build-arg CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD=$$CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD \
    --build-arg CLOUDSQL_DATABASE=$$CLOUDSQL_DATABASE \
    --build-arg CLOUDSQL_SOCKET=$$CLOUDSQL_SOCKET \
    --build-arg OAUTH_PRIVATE_KEY="$$OAUTH_PRIVATE_KEY" \
    --build-arg OAUTH_PUBLIC_KEY="$$OAUTH_PUBLIC_KEY" \
    -f ./purgatory/Dockerfile ./purgatory
  secretEnv: ['CLOUDSQL_DATABASE','CLOUDSQL_USERNAME','CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD','CLOUDSQL_SOCKET','OAUTH_PRIVATE_KEY','OAUTH_PUBLIC_KEY']
  id: Build
```

More information about the public and private keys I'm trying to pass from GCP secrets to the /storage dir in the docker container is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/passport#deploying-passport).

As for the service account, a coworker put that in and it's working as intended as far as I can tell, otherwise I'm not quite sure what it's doing yet. If something with the service account is jumping out as bad practice or I'm missing something else, I welcome feedback.

Comment: Super easy! You don't need a service account key file! Problem solved!!

Comment: Seriously, to help you, you need to explain why you need this key, how you use it, and we will explain you how not to use it! Don't hesitate to share code (dockerfile for instance)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Question updated. Sorry, I don't have much info on the service account key file itself. In this instance, I just kind of leave it there and it works for the moment. Generally, I use service account keys for running locally or connecting to google cloud from a bare-metal server that otherwise isn't a cloud user (basically creating a very-limited service account that the server can use to access some GCP assets). I assume the build and run processes on the cloud, those are already running service accounts and require no extra keys

Comment: Ok, you are running the container outside of Google CLoud, right?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere we run the container both locally using docker-compose and remotely using cloud build and cloud run

Comment: If you run the container on Google Cloud (and Cloud Run is a great choice!), you don't need a service account key file neither during the container build (with Cloud Build) nor with Cloud Run. Using service account key file is generally a bad practice that create security weaknesses.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I checked, and the reason we're using the service account key file (which is stored and retrieved from a GCP secret) is because we couldn't figure out how to get the service account data from within the container to use for the GCP PHP packages. I found another question you answered (61461409) where you suggested using a "metadata server". Is that the missing piece for getting service account creds without using a full json key? What metadata key would correspond to the service account key?

Comment: Why do you need the service account key file data in your project? What do you try to achieve that require these data? (I see only the GCS signed URL feature!)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere After the container and Laravel application are built, the app still needs credentials in order to access Googles service such as bucket storage. For example, we have a file upload Laravel controller that calls bucket storage from within the controller code. Without the service account key file, the call to bucket storage fails

Comment: It depends! If  you run your container on Google Cloud, the Cloud Storage client library leverage metadata server and ADC to get the current runtime credential. So, you could need a key if you run outside GCP your container, on prem for instance.